# Plone 4.0.5 upgrade to 4.1.3

Tags: notifications, plone, upgrade

Basically I installed a fresh 4.1.3. Then I made diff on builout.cfg and base.cfg and copied over the changes.

Then I ran:

> bin/buildout
>    bin/buildout -n

, to update the core and add-on's respectively. Thenafter I ran "Update" as Admin.

Now, problems that are still remaining:

---

In "add-on" Ploneboard 3.2 is reporting problems:

> "Install the intranet workflow definitions for Ploneboard."

There is also a red exclamation mark saying something with:

> "This add-on is upgraded with an old profile version uknown.
>    New profile version is 1.0. There is no upgrade defined for this add-on.
>    Please see the add-on doc for upgrade info, or contact the add-on author."

The PloneboardSubscription 0.2 also shows a red exclamation mark.

---

The "Discussion" link is not shown in the left menu of the "Control Panel" (as in a fresh 4.1.3 install of Plone).

---

Users having æøå in their name can not subscribe to PloneboardSubscription. If so the log (and page) will show this error:

> ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog
>    ...
>    Module Products.PloneboardSubscription.NotificationTool, line 165, in process_pending
>    Module Products.PloneboardSubscription.NotificationTool, line 219, in sendNotification
>    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not
>    in range(128)

---

When making a second comment (or a comment to another comment) the log says:

> ERROR Products.ZCatalog A different document with value
>    'bc33fa86-7cf8-4a68-999f-851cd7d5ffb1' already exists in the index.'
>    None

, the comment functionality is working though.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Comment: The discussion control panel issue is detailed here http://dev.plone.org/ticket/11900

Comment: Thanks. I tried select to "plone.app.discussion:default" in the Upgrades tab menu and hit 'Choose Profile' and ran Upgrade. The upgrade was performed (all → 100), but there is no "Discussion" link in the Control Panel when logged in as Admin. Also, if I make a comment to a comment (or 2 seperate comments) I get this error: ------
2012-01-23T17:35:32 ERROR Products.ZCatalog A different document with value '8df8ddce-4bbf-4351-a373-ec651d6482f0' already exists in the index.'
None ? Thanks. Nikolaj G.